# Multiple UIPickerView in the one TableViewController Programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I've been trying to do this now for several days but I can't find a way that works. The ways I've tried to set it up loads up the pickerviews as keyboards for the textfields which is what I want but it doesn't show any of the data I've put into them. Can someone help me through the setps of this or give me a link to and example of it. Thank you to any helper.

Answer (score 2):

```
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:237.0/255.0 green:30.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)];
    
    doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    
    NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexButton, doneButton, nil];
    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray];
    
    yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    UIPickerView *categoryPicker   = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 216)];
    categoryPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    categoryPicker.delegate = self;
    categoryPicker.dataSource = self;
    categoryPicker.tag = 1;
    yourTextField.inputView  = categoryPicker;
```

after writing all this code in your viewdidappear, implement the delegate and datasource of your pickerview

## pragma mark -UIPickerView Delegate and DataSource

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return  1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return  yourDataSource.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [yourDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    yourTextField.text = [yourDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

and implement a selector for the done button like that

```
- (void)resignKeyboard
{
    [bloodGroupField resignFirstResponder];
}
```